# Position:fixed with overflow:hidden parent does not work

Tags: css

I try to apply overflow:hidden on a child-box that has position:fixed. This appears to not work due to the fixed position. Is there a fix?

http://jsfiddle.net/HFZ7V/

I read about a similar problem with position:absolute elements, but the fixes do not work for fixed elements.

Comment: This is the intended behavior, as the element is being taken out of normal flow when using 'fixed' position. It becomes relative to the document window and no longer to the element it's within.
The only real fix would be to make the parent element fixed instead...

Comment: OK, not possible then. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JordanRynard - I've tried applying it to the parent element, still doesn't seem to be working...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've updated your jsfiddle, with a *guess* of what you're trying to achieve. Let us know if it looks like what you're after.

http://jsfiddle.net/HFZ7V/1/

Comment: Thanks, but it is a requirement that the child-element has position:fixed. I guess this is not possible then, seeing the other comments...